# jQuery - How to get element inside data object function

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to get the element inside a function in an object that was set as 'data' of an element? If there is none, what are some alternative ways to implement this?

```
var m = function(options){
     // Some initialization code here
}

m.prototype.doSomething: function() {
    // How do i get the #an_element here?
}

$("#an_element").data('myObject', m);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that it's to give that element to constructor, you can check it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fustic/3LUTX/15/).

```
var m = function(options){
     // Some initialization code here
    $.extend(this, options);
}

m.prototype.doSomething= function() {
    // How do i get the #an_element here?
    var _this=this;
    if(_this.el && _this.el.length){
        _this.el.css({color:"black"}); 
    }
}
$(function(){
    var $el=$("#an_element");
    $el.data('myobject', new m({el:$el}));
    $el.click(function(){
        var nn=$(this).data("myobject");
        nn.doSomething();
        return false;
    });
});
```

The mistake what you did it's that you trying to put into data the function itself, but you have to create a object before like this: `$("#an_element").data('myObject', new m());`

Comment: I was trying to find a way to avoid having to pass the element to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that u stored a class or id i.e. selector inside #an_element. Try this:

```
var m = function(options){
     // Some initialization code here
}

m.prototype.doSomething: function() {
    var selector = $("#an_element").data('myObject');
    var required_element = $(selector);
}

$("#an_element").data('myObject', m);
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if the selector returns more than one element